# pip3 install [module] creating new "/.local/.../site-packages" directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip, keyboard

relatively new to the raspberry pi and python world. Right now I'm attempting to install:

```
pip3 install keyboard
```

Problem is, it is creating & saving into this folder structure...

```
/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keyboard/
```

It's creating a '.local'? Which I have never seen before. Whenever I launch python3 in the terminal and 'import keyboard'. The module is not found. I've learned the sys.path is only using these directories

```
['', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', 

'/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

This is the first time I've ran into this error. I did setup SublimeText3 & a SFTP Package which syncs Remote >> Local files. I don't see why that would interfere with module installs?

Suggestions I've read to fix the 'module not found' error is to edit the SYSPATH. Instead, **I'd like to know WHY it's creating this new weird directory. And what can I do to make it save to one of the supported sys.path directories?**

---

[Debian Bug Report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=765022) about why site-packages is not used in sys.path

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its a matter of putting sudo before pip3 install [module].... >.<

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the problem, but something to fix it.

Solution: Install the package in your current directory.

```
$ pip3 install -t . keyboard
```

You can see the solution here    [image]

**NB:**

- When ever you need the package you need to install it in your project directory.
- Try installing the package in '/usr/lib/python3.7' path to make is accessible always.